# Hide change markers in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Does anyone know how to hide change markers in PHPStorm?

[image]

Comment: I can't find anything in preferences or the manual, I suspect it's not possible.

Comment: There is NO such option. You will have to either disable VCS integration .. or change those marker's colors to something invisible/same-as-background (`Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts` -- look for styles with "added", "changed", "modified" words in it (use quick search functionality for that)).

Comment: 1. Settings | Version Control : change the VCS to <none> (top-right). 2. Restart PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

*These workarounds are curated from comments on the question above.*

## Option 1: Disable VCS

Settings | Version Control : *Remove VCS for applicable directories*

## Option 2: Change colors

Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts : *Change added/changed/modified to invisible/same-as-background*